# foreach array loop does not always work on Windows

Tags: php

I encounter this very odd scenario. The PHP is below:

```
$complete_categories_list=array();

foreach ($modules_library_processed as $key=>$modules_categories_rendered) {
    foreach ($modules_categories_rendered['modulecategories'] as $module_category_key=>$module_category_values) {
        foreach ((array) $module_category_values as $module_key_inner=>$module_category_value) {
            $complete_categories_list[]=trim($module_category_value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is working perfectly in Unix/Linux localhost and in some instances will work in Windows localhost. But not all of them. The problem is that at the end of the loop, `$complete_categories_list` is empty even though `$modules_library_processed` has some data on it. `$modules_library_processed` is a very large array, so I cannot post the entire data here. I hope someone can shed light on this.

**UPDATE:** The source is an XML file 
`simplexml_load_string($modules_xml_exported);` which I converted to an array. The result is `$modules_library_processed`.

`print_r($module_category_values)` results to SimpleXMLElement Object ()

But I typecasted it to an array..so that should work right?

Comment: That's odd. What does `$modules_library_processed` look like? Any chance that it's split by *nix-specific newlines?

Comment: Not sure it's related, but why are you typecasting `$module_category_values` to an array?

Comment: Same PHP version on the two machines?

Comment: Can you share the $modules_library_processed array structure?

Comment: @I have updated my question. The data is actually coming from an XML file which I converted into an array. I will try to find ways to show it here..so you can see the structure.

Comment: print_r($module_category_values) results to SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) does this have an effect in Windows?

Comment: there some reason you need to have the script work for windows hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have fixed the problem The root cause is the script processing SimpleXML which does not play when the script is run under Windows even though with all the Type casting, etc. I ended up rewriting my scripts so it won't output any SimpleXML element but all in array/string format. I hope this helps someone. Thanks.